# Java program compiled by more recent version of JRE, but I have the most recent version

Tags: java, minecraft, jre

I'm trying to set up a Minecraft server for my friends and I get the following error every time I try to launch it

```
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class net.minecraft.bundler.Main
    java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
    net/minecraft/bundler/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0),
    this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0
```

(copied and pasted)

I have the current JRE available on Ubuntu (build 11.0.15.10). I've tried removing all versions of JRE on my server and reinstalling only the most recent one, but I get the same error.
I even updated the whole server from Ubuntu 18 to Ubuntu 20. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You haven't been specific with release details, but mention Ubuntu 18 upgraded to Ubuntu 20 - so you're using a Ubuntu Core 20 server system? (not 20.04; the *year* products differing to the more common *year.month* systems)

Answer (score 5):

from your error you have to know that Java 17 = class file version 61.0
Java 11 = class file version 55.0

So you need to install Java 17. By default Ubuntu have this command `sudo apt install default-jre` which will install some version of the JRE on your system. Now because you want exactly Java 17 you can try to execute `sudo apt install openjdk-17-jre-headless`. If this result in error because it is not in the Repository of Ubuntu you can check some tutorial like this to installed it manually:
https://techviewleo.com/install-java-openjdk-on-ubuntu-linux/

In your system there is already Java 11. To switch which version you need: `sudo update-alternatives --config java` The you have to choose the number of the row with the right JVM.

Good luck to all!